# IBM DataStage : ODBC_Connector_0: Schema reconciliation detected a size mismatch for column

Tags: datastage, ibm-infosphere

I have this job where i input from the source to the target database. I set the Set Fail on size mismatch to "No", the error is `ODBC_Connector_0: Schema reconciliation detected a size mismatch for column plafon. When reading database column DECIMAL(15,2) into column INT32, truncation, loss of precision, data corruption or padding can occur.` in the previous job this trick works but somehow with this new job it does not work. Is the only way to fix it is with this [closure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.conn.drs.usage.doc/topics/DRS061.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting data implicitly - and in your case even data types - this can cause a lot of trouble so the message is right.

Suggested solution:
Convert explicitly - either in SQL with CAST or within DataStage.